# How to Keep CheckListBox In correct Location when maximizing form

Tags: c#

So, When I do not maximize the Screen, My Locations of things are in place, as you see in photo 1:

[image: Photo 1]

but when I maximize my screen, it looks like this in Photo 2:

I have tried to change my anchors and tried docking it to the bottom but nothing seems to be working. What Do I do to make it to stay in it's location, like in photo 1, when the form is maximized?

[image: Photo 2]

Comment: It is staying in its location, which appears to be the problem. How about you explain what you actually want? I'm guessing that is for the `Button` to always be in the bottom-left corner of the form and the `CheckedListBox` to always fill the space above it. Is that correct?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: Please, delete this question, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), come back later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess what you actually want and modify the answer if I get it wrong. I suspect that what you have failed to explain is that you want the `Button` to always be in the same position with respect to the bottom-left corner of the form and the `CheckedListBox` to fill the space above it, i.e. always be in the same position with respect to the left side and both the top and bottom of the form. When you explain it fully like that, the solution should become obvious, i.e. you set the `Anchor` of the `Button` to `Left` and `Bottom`  and you set the `Anchor` of the `CheckedListBox` to `Top`, `Left` and `Bottom`. You might look at [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?630636) for more.

Default size:

[image]

Maximised:

[image]

Comment: What I want is to have the button on the left bottom side, no matter the form size and have the CheckedListBox on the top left side, above the button... However, I have tried your solution but it shows the ListBox wrong when doing so.